# What consequences could it have to make my apps use a "non-installed" (bundled) java?

Tags: java

What i mean is, instead of installing a java version on my clients, to just put a java folder and make my apps use java.exe from that folder?

Why i want to do this you may ask? because installing java the default way, it can be automatic updated, which may cause the java installation folder to change. As i have apps that must run on windows task scheduler, where i have to put absolute path from java.exe to make it work, if the installation folder changes due to an update, it will cause my app to suddenly stop working.

So, instead of calling my apps like this:
`c:\program files\java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe -jar MyApp.jar`
I would call it like this:
`c:\myApplicationFolder\java\bin\java.exe -jar MyApp.jar`

Is this a bad practice? Or is it safe to do? Can i face some problems doing it?

Comment: Mojang is using a custom java build for minecraft, I believe openoffice uses such a thing too. That way you know for certain what the java version you distributes is capable of and supports. It's not bad practise per se, since java is very fragmented and can give debugging nigtmares when a client still has java 6 that executes your code. I'm following to see what the general consensus will be of other people in the field.

Comment: Is there no other way of determining where java.exe is?  Your way sounds ilke a fun way of using an out of date java which is a security risk.

Comment: @Alex Actually when java is installed, an environment variable should be created, JAVA_HOME, which points to the java folder, but sometimes when updating java version (I saw this behavior on windows), this variable is not updated correctly and after installation, it points to a non-existent folder.

Comment: Yes, I suspected as much which is why I typed but decided not to post it in my comment. I also didn't mention the registry, as your situation seems platform independent.   You could require the clients to create another enviroment variable and ensure that's always up to date. Or you could assume that the location of java.exe is in the path somewhere and interrogate that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically you want to bundle the Java runtime to manage the dependency yourself.  That is not a bad idea at all.  As you said, it eliminates a lot of support issues like "This app doesn't work on my PC!  Why not?"

If the downside to using an already-installed JVM is that it can automatically update itself, then the upside is also that it can automatically update itself.

What I mean by that is, consider the following issues:

1. Security problems - Over the last few years, Java has had a number of security vulnerabilities discovered.  If I remember right, they were mainly related to browser plugins for applets, so that may not be a problem for you, but the general point still stands.  When a client has their own installation of Java, they automatically get security fixes.
2. You are responsible for updating Java.  You need to both invest the man hours periodically to keep the bundled JVM current and repeat your testing and also need a release cadence that is short enough to deploy these Java updates periodically.  You've essentially made yourself responsible for your customers' JVM's.

That said, these costs may not be that high, given a few conditions.  If you have these conditions, it may not be a big deal:

1. Automatic updates of *your* app.  If your app, once installed on a client's machine, automatically pulls down new releases within a few days of release, then you are unlikely to have non-current versions out there for long.  And if somebody is running a 6-month old version with a known bug, "Upgrade" becomes a more acceptable answer if they are 12 versions behind.
2. Short release cycle, which to many people, is a good thing to have anyway.  If you are already releasing weekly, or even monthly, then again, you can get updates out easily.
3. Customizations - If you customize the JVM in any way, you increase the development and testing cost of upgrading your bundled JVM.  If you leave it alone and the installer simply unpacks it, then upgrading the bundled JVM is cheap.  You could even automate it at that point.  Just grab the latest, check it in, and run your tests.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle JRE 8 README explicitly permits it: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html

There is a small licensing caveat, however. In short, you have to include the whole JRE with a only a limited number of exceptions, and you can also include some parts of the JDK, for example the tools.jar that is used by tomcat6 IIRC.

Check the Redistribution section in the README for full details.

Years ago, we distributed an application with the JRE included, and we renamed java.exe to something more descriptive, so system administrators would know what it was that was running on their machines. I think our legal department had to clear that with Sun at the time. Can't figure out if that would still be within Oracle's licensing terms or not.